# Writing Æ,ø,å using XeTeX

Tags: xetex

I would like to use the danish letters "æ,ø,å" with xelatex. Everything works just fine if i use pdflatex, but if i use xelatex "æ,ø,å" are not printed.

I have tried several different fonts. I have tried loading external fonts also. I am using TeX live on Windows 8. Here is a minimal example:

```
% Setup
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
% Document
\begin{document}
Hæst.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your file works for me with texlive2012 xelatex. Make sure that it is saved as utf-8, if the character does not appear you could post the log file to your question.

Comment: You are absolutely correct! Emacs was saving in latin1 by default. I didn't know that pdflatex and xetex were different at that point. Converting all files to UTF-8 solved the problem.

Comment: Glad you got it working. As that's the issue I suggested closing this as duplicate, the answer in the linked question has some other things to watch out for when switching from pdftex to xetex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your MWE compiles just fine with XeLaTeX in TeXworks using TeX Live 2012 on Windows 7, without the need to change any of the default features that came with TeX Live or TeXworks:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\begin{document}
Hæst.
\end{document}
```

> This is XeTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.4-0.9998 (TeX Live 2012/W32TeX)
>   (format=xelatex 2013.3.14)  14 JUN 2013 13:53

[image]